# How to put the filters on cosmos database CreateDocumentQuery using C#

Tags: .net, azure, c#-4.0, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a following json string stored as a document in azure cosmos db.

```
 {
"id": "e1e83377-dbb2-cfd2-e681-d46aba367956",
"DateCreated": "2018-09-17T19:07:20.243Z",
"Lists":
 [
  { 
  "number":"1",
  "Name":"Doctor"
  },
  { 
  "number":"2",
  "Name": "Lawyer"
  }
 ]
"Type": "Call",
"IsActive": true,
"Brands":
 [
    5,
    19
 ]
}
```

I want to get the items such that the filter is `Lists.number.Contains(2) && IsActive==true && Type=="Call" && Brands.Contains(5)`
then the above json should be returned as a response. I have the following Query to fetch the result

```
IDocumentQuery<object> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<object>(
            UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(Constants.C4CosmosDatabaseId, collectionId),
            _feedOptions).AsDocumentQuery();
        
        var results = new List<object>();
        while (query.HasMoreResults)
        {
            results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync());
        }
```

**I want to achieve the filter on query without creating the model class for the json string as I did already as follows**:

```
IDocumentQuery<Class> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Class>(
            UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(Constants.C4CosmosDatabaseId, collectionId),
            _feedOptions).Where(x => x.Type== "Call"&& x.Brands.Contains(5) && x.IsActive==true).AsDocumentQuery();
```

Comment: Any Help I can expect?

Answer (score 0):

Would this answer help you? You can construct a query using JOINs and provide the query as input to the CreateDocumentQuery API.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32658038/2338641

Comment: I want to achieve something like this way but im getting empty results:     
                                                                                                             IDocumentQuery<JObject> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<JObject>(
                UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(Constants.C4CosmosDatabaseId, 
              collectionId), _feedOptions)
                .Where(x => x["Brands"].Contains(5) && (int)x["Lists"]["number"] == 2)
                .AsDocumentQuery();